# Error while trying to create vertica udx in java

Tags: java, sql, vertica

I'm trying to create a Vertica UDx

JAR is generated via

```
javac -classpath /opt/vertica/bin/VerticaSDK.jar BuildInfo.java TestFactory.java Test.java -d output/ 
jar -cvf TestLib.jar BuildInfo.class output/*.class
```

Loading into DB via

```
CREATE LIBRARY TestFunctions AS '/home/dbadmin/test/TestLib.jar' LANGUAGE 'JAVA';
```

Getting the error

```
SQL Error [2175] [55000]: [Vertica][VJDBC](2175) ROLLBACK: An error occurred when loading library file on node v_test_node0002, message: Failure in UDx RPC call InvokeCheckLibrary(): Error in User Defined Object [], error code: 0 Error happened in loading jar file, the user library might be built with a new version of JDK

[Vertica][VJDBC](2175) ROLLBACK: An error occurred when loading library file on node v_test_node0002, message: Failure in UDx RPC call InvokeCheckLibrary(): Error in User Defined Object [], error code: 0 Error happened in loading jar file, the user library might be built with a new version of JDK

com.vertica.util.ServerException: [Vertica][VJDBC](2175) ROLLBACK: An error occurred when loading library file on node vtest_node0002, message: Failure in UDx RPC call InvokeCheckLibrary(): Error in User Defined Object [], error code: 0 Error happened in loading jar file, the user library might be built with a new version of JDK
```

Local & remote server's JDK version are the same 1.8.0_131

Vertica version 8.0.1

```
JAR tree
├── com
│   └── vertica
│       ├── JavaLibs
│       │   ├── Test.class
│       │   └── TestFactory.class
│       └── sdk
│           └── BuildInfo.class
VERTICA_BUILD_ID_Brand_Version    = "v8.0.1-5";
```

Comment: What version of Vertica?

Comment: brand version 8.0.1-5

Comment: Is VerticaSDK.jar in your build path?

Comment: what do you mean by build path ?

Comment: Gah, sorry -- fingers got ahead of brain.  I meant to ask about classpath, but since it built ok that doesn't seem like it would be the problem.  Have you tried loading the examples to see if they produce the same errors?  There are .sql files in the distro along with the code.

Comment: can you post a structure of `jar` library (`jar` is a simple zip file), i.e. post output of `unzip -l TestLib.jar`. I think that directory `output` in a `jar` file

Comment: also can you post content of `BuildInfo.java` or just variable `VERTICA_BUILD_ID_Brand_Version`?

Comment: @sKwa updated in main question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this issue by compiling it on the server

to make this answer more informative :

```
$ ls
```

> ```
> TestFactory.java  Test.java
> ```

```
# compile all java files with VerticaSDK & BuildInfo
$ javac -classpath /opt/vertica/bin/VerticaSDK.jar /opt/vertica/sdk/BuildInfo.java *.java -d .
# show compiled files
$ find . -type f
```

> ```
> ./com/vertica/sdk/BuildInfo.class
> ./com/vertica/JavaLibs/TestFactory.class
> ./com/vertica/JavaLibs/Test.class
> ./TestFactory.java
> ./Test.java
> ```

```
# combine compiled classes into single jar
$ jar -cvf TestLib.jar com/vertica/sdk/BuildInfo.class com/vertica/JavaLibs/*.class
```

> ```
> added manifest
> adding: com/vertica/sdk/BuildInfo.class(in = 1315) (out= 749)(deflated 43%)
> adding: com/vertica/JavaLibs/Test.class(in = 1238) (out= 717)(deflated 42%)
> adding: com/vertica/JavaLibs/TestFactory.class(in = 916) (out= 435)(deflated 52%)
> ```

```
$ ls
```

> ```
> com  TestFactory.java  Test.java  TestLib.jar
> ```

load & use function

```
CREATE LIBRARY TestFunctions AS '/path/TestLib.jar' LANGUAGE 'JAVA';

CREATE ANALYTIC FUNCTION a_test AS LANGUAGE 'java' NAME 'com.vertica.JavaLibs.TestFactory' LIBRARY TestFunctions;

SELECT a_test(col, args) OVER (ORDER BY col2) FROM ...
```